# A CFG for the language $\{ O^i 1^j 2^k 3^l : i=k, j>1 , l>0 \}$: Is my approach correct?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am trying to construct a CFG for the CFL $\{ O^i 1^j 2^k 3^l : i=k, j>1 , l>0 \}$.
When given $i=2$, $k=2$, $j=2$, and $l=1$, this yields the string $0011223$.

My approach:
$$\begin{align}
S &\Rightarrow A \\
A &\Rightarrow OAB \mid \varepsilon \\
B &\Rightarrow 1B1C \mid \varepsilon \\
C &\Rightarrow 2CD \mid \varepsilon \\
D &\Rightarrow 3D \mid \varepsilon
\end{align}$$

Please explain to me the thought-process associated when solving such problems, I keep on getting similar answers for all questions, and don't know how to properly tackle them. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of $\newcommand{\Ze}{\mathtt{0}}\newcommand{\On}{\mathtt{1}}\newcommand{\Tw}{\mathtt{2}}\newcommand{\Th}{\mathtt{3}}\Ze$s must equal the number of $\Tw$s, a good idea is to start basing your CFG around the usual CFG for the language $\{ \Ze^n \Tw^n : n \geq 0 \}$, namely $$S \rightarrow \Ze S \Tw \mid \varepsilon.$$  We see for the language in question that there are at least two $\On$s in between the $\Ze$s and $\Tw$s, and so we can alter the above rule as follows: $$\begin{align*}
S &\rightarrow \Ze S \Tw \mid T \\
T &\rightarrow \On T \mid \On \On
\end{align*}$$  Next we have to worry about the $\Th$s.  Since we only need a positive number of them at the end of the string with no relationship necessary to any of the other symbols, we can introduce a new start symbol that will just split off into the part of the grammar we have introduced so far, and a part that will generate the $\Th$s: $$\begin{align}
S_0 &\rightarrow S U \\
S &\rightarrow \Ze S \Tw \mid T \\
T &\rightarrow \On T \mid \On \On \\
U &\rightarrow \Th U \mid \Th
\end{align}$$  And we're done.

---

Among other strings, your grammar will generate the following:

1. $\varepsilon$ (generated by $S \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow \varepsilon$);
2. $\Ze \Ze \Ze$ (generated by $S \Rightarrow A \Rightarrow \Ze A B \Rightarrow \Ze \Ze A B B \Rightarrow \Ze \Ze \Ze A B B B \Rightarrow \Ze \Ze \Ze \varepsilon \varepsilon \varepsilon \varepsilon = \Ze \Ze \Ze$);

which are not in the language.  Upon inspection, I think your grammar generates the language $$\{ \Ze^m ( \On^n ( \On \Tw^* \Th^* )^n )^m : n , m \geq 0 \}$$

Comment: so a good way of approaching such problems is to first handle the common cases, i.e same number of 0s and 2s, and then work from there since we have a semi-answer already? I was thinking of including the 1st as soon as I saw the answer. In particular, I am interested in your thought process. Now all of a sudden the answer looks easy but I just couldn't solve it and you did in minutes. Please share some tips with me.

Comment: @Gaak: Again, its mostly practice, and having a repertoire of stock CFGs/PDAs/etc. to handle these common cases at your disposal.  It's always good to look for patterns in the language before beginning to write out rules, and ensure that if there must be a connection between certain symbols, they are generated at approximately the same time.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for your time - I appreciate it